# Change view after calling ajax in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I need help with angularJS. I call ajax as follows:

```
$scope.$watch('value1', function() {
  if ($scope.value1 != null) {
    $http({
      method : 'GET',
      url : 'http://localhost:8080/program1/api/verify?post='+$scope.value1
    }).success(function (result) {                                              
      $scope.data1 = result;      
      console.log("ajax->"+$scope.value2);
    });
  }
});
```

In my view i have the folloing code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <select ng-model="data1"
          ng-options="data for data in data1">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select> 
  {{data1}}
</div>
```

My problem is that the dropdown doesn't change in the view. 
Could anyone help me about it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: sorry. I want to correct something in code above. In the first line i have written $scope.watch('data1', function... and not $scope.$watch('value1', ...

Comment: @stavorsKouris so click the edit and edit it.

Comment: A JSFiddle may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you issue is your `ng-options` and `ng-model` are using the same property `data1`.

When you select a value that selected value is bound to the property of `ng-model` so that is `data1` however your `ng-options` is using `data1` so it gets overwritten.

So basically your `ng-options` and `ng-model` should use two different properties of your scope. One representing the selected value, the other being the array of values to populate the options.
see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1uzyoLmr/

```
<select ng-model="data1"
        ng-options="d for d in data">
    <option value=""></option>
</select> 
{{data1}}
```

and your controller

```
$scope.data1;
$scope.data = [10, 11, 23];
```

Docs for reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: I would be grateful if you helped me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oLxhf7a0/1/ Hopefully this updated fiddle will help. This is quite easy. You just set your dropdown data sources from your ajax. It being async doesn't matter angular will do the hard work thanks to its data binding